# Discord bot perms config

Tags: python-3.x

I need help with configuring permissions for a discord bot in python 3 i have tried some things but nothing worked such as setting the admin true but nothing worked.

```
@client.command()
async def clear(ctx, amount=5):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
```